# In ColdFusion is it possible to pass an array to a custom tag?

Tags: arrays, coldfusion, cfml, custom-tags

I want to pass an array to a custom tag. Is this possible?
I have an arry arrayProd. In my cfm I am calling the custom tag :

```
<cf_cu_show_productcategories thename="#thename#" thenameprod="#thenameprod#" arrayProd="#arrayProd#">
```

The custom tag :

```
<cfparam name="attributes.thename" default="">
<cfparam name="attributes.thenameprod" default="">
<cfparam name="attributes.arrayProd" type="array" default="">
```

Using this arrayProd in de custom tag results in 'Variable ARRAYPROD is undefined'.

Comment: How do you access `ARRAYPROD` that results in the error message?

Comment: Indeed, I found out that I access it only by arryProd and not by attributes.arrayProd. Thank you.

Comment: Use the attributes scope when accessing custom tags attributes. So it should be Attributes.arrayProd.

Comment: @Bernard Döbler; could you maybe write your comment as an answer to this post so I can set it to solved? It was indeed your remark that led me to the fact that I forgot to use attributes.arrayProd. Now I cannot mark this post as solved.

Answer (score 5):

Default attribute should be `default="#[]#"`

Comment: Or an old fashioned `default="#ArrayNew(1)#"`.

Comment: True. Though it still throws an undefined error for me even with the change.  Guess I'd forgotten CF doesn't include `attributes` when evaluating unscoped variables, like @Redtopia and Veni inferred in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58265590/in-coldfusion-is-it-possible-to-pass-an-array-to-a-custom-tag#comment102910111_58265590